# When does MonoDevelop generate the Connect syntax

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I've been at this for more then a day now and I'm pulling out my hairs here. I'm trying to implement the RedLaser example into my own app but MonoDevelop/MonoTouch just doesn't generate the right code. It must be something I'm (not) doing in Interface Builder. Ok here goes.

In the sample in the 'RLSampleViewController.xib.designer.cs the following is generated:

```
namespace RedLaserSample {


    // Base type probably should be MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController or subclass
    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("RLSampleViewController")]
    public partial class RLSampleViewController {

        private OverlayController __mt_overlayController;
   ....

        [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("overlayController")]
        private OverlayController overlayController {
            get {
                this.__mt_overlayController = ((OverlayController)(this.GetNativeField("overlayController")));
                return this.__mt_overlayController;
            }
            set {
                this.__mt_overlayController = value;
                this.SetNativeField("overlayController", value);
            }
        }
```

In my code the following is generated:

```
namespace Winkel
{
    [Register ("ScanArtikelController")]
    partial class ScanArtikelController
    {
        [Outlet]
        Winkel.OverlayController overlayController { get; set; }
```

So the 'Connect' syntax is not generated and I have no clue how to define this correctly in Interface Builder.

Something else I noticed. There must be a different generator active then in my code. This is what was generated for the RedLaser example:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <autogenerated>
//      This code was generated by a tool.
//      Mono Runtime Version: 4.0.30319.1
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if 
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </autogenerated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and this comment was generated for my code:

```
// WARNING
//
// This file has been generated automatically by MonoDevelop to store outlets and
// actions made in the Xcode designer. If it is removed, they will be lost.
// Manual changes to this file may not be handled correctly.
//
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the sample code you have is outdated. That is what previous versions of MonoDevelop (<=2.6) would generate when Interface Builder was a standalone application.

Now that Interface Builder is integrated into Xcode, your code is what MonoDevelop (>= 2.8) generates.

Regarding functionality, both code snippets are the same, meaning they will both create a property which will reflect your connected outlet in interface designer with the type `OverlayController`.